# Assigning value to char ** seg faulting

Tags: c

I have a program that parses a text file, and stores it in a pointer array. I have only one problem. I'm trying to store an array of strings in a `char **` object, but whenever I assign a value to the `char **`, I get seg faults.

```
#include "database.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char **get_values(int recipe_num, char *file) {
    int placehold_num=recipe_num;
    char *text=parse_recipes(file);
    int num_recipes=count_recipes(file);
    char **array_strings;
    int index=-1;
    for (int i=0;*(text+i)!='\0';i++) {
        if (*(text+i)=='R' && *(text+i+1)=='e' && *(text+i+6)==':' && (text+i+7)==' ') {
            i+=13;
            index++;
            for (int j=0;*(text+i+j-1)!='\n';j++) {
                printf("%c",*(text+i+j));
                *(*(array_strings+index)+j)=*(text+i+j);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

This prints out the char I want from `*(text+i+j)`, but seg faults on the next line. I'm extremely sure it isn't a problem with another function being called, I think it must be something with the way I'm dereferencing `array_strings`. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. And what did your debugger tell you?

Comment: You've never allocated any memory for `array_strings` to point to.

Comment: `text + i + j` is not the correct way to access an element of a 2-dimensional array. It should be `text + i*row_size + j`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in

```
*(*(array_strings+index)+j)=*(text+i+j);
```

You create a variable

```
char** array_strings;
```

It is now pointing to some garbage, you can see the current address just by calling

```
print("%p\n", array_strings);
```

I strongly recommend to initialize `array_strings` by `NULL`, because once you can receive a pointer to memory, where you can write, and it will write to some place, where your other data can be stored, and you will just destroy both data. And if it is `NULL` you'll always receive `segfault`. So, at the moment you are trying to assign a value `*(text+i+j)` to a random place in the memory.

To do, what you want, you have to

```
char** array_strings = (char**)malloc(n * sizeof(char*));
```

where n is an amount of strings you need, and then in cycle do

```
array_strings[some_your_index] = text+i+j;
```

`array_strings[some_your_index]` is now `char*`, as `text+i+j` is.

Comment: See: [**Do I cast the result of malloc?**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714) `char **array_strings = malloc (sizeof *array_strings);` is sufficient. You then need to allocate for each string, e.g. `array_strings[i] = malloc (strlen(str) + 1);`

Comment: Thank you for that article, really interesting. I can just use my `char*` pointers, to point the strings, separated, for example, by `\0` in the old big string. Also, for me it is more difficult to read `sizeof *array_strings` than `sizeof char*`, and I think it is not a problem to write like that